Retrieving relevant documents for specific queries
I am trying to retrieve the top 5 relevant documents related to a user's query using the RAG-Token model. I'm using a custom knowledge base and I tried adjusting the retrieval parameters.
This is the code:
# Include a minimal, complete, and verifiable example of the code you are using
from transformers import RagTokenizer, RagTokenForGeneration, RagRetriever

tokenizer = RagTokenizer.from_pretrained("facebook/rag-token-nq")
model = RagTokenForGeneration.from_pretrained("facebook/rag-token-nq")
retriever = RagRetriever.from_pretrained("facebook/rag-token-nq", index_name="custom", passages_path="my_knowledge_dataset")

input_query = "What is the impact of AI in healthcare?"
input_ids = tokenizer(input_query, return_tensors="pt").input_ids

# Generate a response
output_ids = model.generate(input_ids)
print("Generated Response:", tokenizer.decode(output_ids[0], skip_special_tokens=True))

I expect the model to retrieve accurate and relevant documents that provide deep insights into the query. However, the retrieved documents are often irrelevant, and the generated answers often do not properly incorporate the retrieved information.
What might be going wrong here? How can I modify the code or change parameter values to get more relevant results?

General suggestion would be to fine-tune Bert model (or any other LLM) on your dataset and add embeddings from this your industry specic Bert model

To enhance the relevance of the documents retrieved by the RAG-Token model and the quality of answers produced, consider fine-tuning the retriever on your custom knowledge base, adjusting retrieval parameters, and ensuring your knowledge base contains high-quality, relevant information. Additionally, refine your query wording and validate generated answers against retrieved documents for accuracy.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
